# Testing Dynamically Set Constants in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a Rails initializer which creates some constants from a config file like so:

```
Kernel.const_set "MailChimp", Module.new
config["lists"].each_pair {|k,v| MailChimp.const_set "#{k}_List".upcase, v} if config
```

Later, I have an observer subscriber a user to a list:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue Jobs::NewsletterSubscriptionJob.new(MailChimp::NEWSLETTER_SUBSCRIBERS_LIST, record)
```

When I test this in RSpec,

```
Kernel.const_set :MailChimp, Module.new
MailChimp.const_set :NEWSLETTER_SUBSCRIBERS_LIST, "foo"
```

I get **uninitialized constant UserObserver::MailChimp**

I have seen some answers related to constants in specs, but I can't seem to get this to work.

How do I set these constants in RSpec so I can test the observer?

FYI: This is Ruby 1.8.7 code.

Comment: in your observer, try: `Delayed::Job.enqueue Jobs::NewsletterSubscriptionJob.new(::MailChimp::NEWSLETTER_SUBSCRIBERS_LIST, record)
`

Comment: The effect was to change the error to `uninitialized constant MailChimp`

Comment: what if you use `Object.const_set`?